# Write an SQL query to find all those hostnames that have encountered multiple logs //“init failure” on any given day at 5 min interval

Tags: sql

Write an SQL query to find all those hostnames that have encountered multiple logs 
“init failure” on any given day at 5 min interval. Also provide count of such log instance.

```
//Hostlogs

//date, time, hostname, logs

//may 20, 2019 8:00 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:01 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:02 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:03 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:04 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:12 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:13 abc init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:00 xyz init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:20 xyz init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:30 xyz init failure
//may 20, 2019 8:30 xyz wxyz
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Any Database can be used.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use `lag()`/`lead()` to find such "adjacent" rows.  Date functions are notoriously database dependent, but the idea is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(time, 4) over (partition by hostname, date order by time) as time_4
      from t
      where log = 'init failure'
     ) t
where time_4 <= time + interval '5 minute';
```

Answer (score 0):

This was one of my interview questions. I had only 15 minutes and I couldn't finish it on time. I spent 2 hours after the interview to solve it. I'm not sure why some interviewers use these tricky questions. Unless you have seen the question before, it is not easy to come up with a solution right on spot in 15 minutes. Anyway, this is my answer:

```
with db1 as (
  select *, 
    lead(time) over (partition by hostname order by date asc, time asc) as lead_time,
    lag(time,1) over (partition by hostname order by date asc, time asc) as lag_time1,
    lag(time,2) over (partition by hostname order by date asc, time asc) as lag_time2,
    lag(time,3) over (partition by hostname order by date asc, time asc) as lag_time3,
    lag(time,4) over (partition by hostname order by date asc, time asc) as lag_time4

  from log
  where logs = 'init failure'),
  db2 as (
  select date, time,hostname, lead_time, lag_time1, lag_time2, lag_time3, lag_time4,
    case when lead_time < time + interval 5 minute then 1 else 0 end as cond1,
    case when lag_time1 > time - interval 5 minute then 1 else 0 end as cond2
  from db1
  ),
  db3 as (
  select date, time,hostname, lead_time, lag_time1, lag_time2, lag_time3, lag_time4, cond1, cond2,
    case when (cond1 = 1) or (cond2 = 1) then TRUE else FALSE end as eligible
  from db2),
  db4 as (
  select date, time,hostname, 
    case 
      when (cond1 = 1) and (cond2 = 0) then time
      when (cond2 = 1) and (time - interval 4 minute = lag_time4) then lag_time4
      when (cond2 = 1) and (time - interval 3 minute = lag_time3) then lag_time3
      when (cond2 = 1) and (time - interval 2 minute = lag_time2) then lag_time2
      when (cond2 = 1) and (time - interval 1 minute = lag_time1) then lag_time1
      else NULL 
      end as start_time
  from db3
  where eligible = TRUE
  )
select date, hostname, count(*)
from db4
group by date, hostname, start_time
```

Comment: BTW, In db4, the order of when conditions matter. If you change the order, it doesn't work.